# How to delete delayed messages before they arrive at a Handler?

Tags: android, handler, message

My Problem is that I need to send messages with a delay of 1 second. The handler then initiates some action, you're getting the picture.

There are nevertheless some conditions in which the already sent message should be deleted ( before the second elapsed ) to prevent the handler from doing anything. I couldn't figure out how to do this ( or if it's even possible ), so If anyone of you has a clue, please let me know..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is nothing scary about the `removeMessages()` methods; they are perfectly safe. The framework relies heavily on these methods and they are used in many many places, especially in the default widgets (`View`, `ListView`, etc.) It's much much better than building a `Handler` that ignores specific messages. This is programming, don't go with your feelings :p

Comment: It would help if there were more documentation on those methods, if the 'what' parameter were available on all enqueuing mechanisms (e.g., postRunnable()), if the distinction between 'what' and 'token' were clearer, etc. If I have to rummage through Android source code to figure out what Handler is doing today, that means I have no guarantees that such undocumented behavior will remain consistent tomorrow. Hence, removeMessages() are, IMHO, scary for developers to rely upon. It won't take much to clear this up, but I can't make decisions for what is and is not appropriate Handler behavior.

Comment: that last sentence of yours made my day, clearly. But besides, I also agree with commonsaware that the documentation is really insufficient in that field, maybe I should just file a ticket.

Comment: There's no reason to have a "what" when you post a Runnable, you just use removeCallback() for this.

What exactly is not guaranteed from the documentation?

Answer (score 6):

Many developers and much of the source code you'll find will show people passing anonymous functions to a handler, so I think in some cases you may be unsure how to remove these.  A simple solution is to declare your runnable as you would any other object, and keep a pointer to it which can be used to clear any instance of it from the Handler queue.

```
private Runnable lastMyRunnablePtr = null;
```

...

```
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{}
```

....

```
lastMyRunnablePtr = new MyRunnable();
mHandler.postDelayed(lastMyRunnablePtr ,30000);
```

....

```
protected void onDestroy() {
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(lastMyRunnablePtr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should consider the implementation of `handler.removeMessages(int, obj)`. If the obj is an object related to autoboxing, you will meet a problem of the implementation of android `MessageQueue`.

For following code snippet, the removeMessages won't work as a result of auto-boxing, [boxing-conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and the implemetation of MessageQueue using p.obj == object to compare object.

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(what, 256);
handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, delayMillis);
handler.removeMessages(what, 256);
```

Ref this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190851/android-os-handler-removemessages-doesnt-work-when-poxing-value-type-as-msg-obj).